# where can I find solutions to A comprehensive introduction to differential geometry by Spivak?

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I have tried google and I fail to find solutions to the exercises in the book A comprehensive Introduction to differenial geometry volume I by Spivak. Does anyone know about a site with solutions to these exercises?

Alternatively can anyone recommend me a similar book with exercises that I can find solutions to?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Typically, answer books are reserved only for instructors for obvious reasons. Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Alternatively can anyone recommend me a similar book with exercises that I can find solutions to?

Take a look at [Analysis and Algebra on Differentiable Manifolds: A Workbook for Students](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=PQ0tHdtC3QwC), by P. M. Gadea, J. Munoz Masqué

Comment: Thanks. I checked it out, it seems good.